# Can benchmarking and auditing help a young software organization?

Tags: leadership, consulting

For an organization creating a first software product, does it make sense to pay a consultant to guide and audit the product team?

Areas where our team is lacking expertise are:

- Selling a generic software product (i.e. *one product many customers*)
- managed software development (something like SCRUM)
- Building a large, configurable program that interacts with multiple external components, and is built for maintainability.

I made the suggestion to hire a consultant to guide us through the early stages of building the software product team, but I neither know what to expect from such a consultant and where to find a suitable one. I am hoping to somehow avoid architectural blunders in our product and inefficiencies in our development process that will hurt in the long run. So I imagined hiring someone experienced to help set priorities for the team until it has developed its own expertise and proven dynamics.

Does this make any sense? Or are there better ways to support building a new software organization?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ouch, this makes us sound really bad. We're growing from selling software on a per-customer basis to building an off the shelf application. And yes, getting people is a challenge since we're located in an isolated rural area.

Comment: This is not really the type of question that the workplace deals with.  It is more of a business question.    I would suggest programmers SE but they do not accept questions there that are not immediately applicable to their power user base...  I doubt this fits.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Navigating the Workplace as described in the [help]

Comment: Is this question related? http://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/does-it-make-sense-to-pay-for-benchmarking-and-auditing I don't want to accuse you of cross-posting. Maybe somebody else just had the same problem at the same time. :-)

Comment: @s1lv3r yes, it's the same issue. It seemed like it might be more on-topic there, so I tried re-wording it.  But as you can see, it's not getting much traction. I tried it anon to get feedback unrelated to this post, but I see it was pointless : )

Comment: @RafaelCichocki Never mind. Hope you are getting the information you are looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Can benchmarking and auditing help a young software organization?

For a young company entering the world of off-the-shelf software, I don't think benchmarking and auditing would be a primary focus.

Instead, consider hiring someone (probably permanently) with the requisite experience to lead your transition. Someone with depth in the type of software you are planning to build, and with experience sourcing and hiring consultants and employees.

Comment: Where does one look for such people - HR firms, consulting firms? No offence to our HR... Do any places to look come in mind to you?

Comment: To expand your pool of possible candidates, consider making the lead job one that is done through telecommuting. I have worked with many such leads throguh the years and it can be done well and then you don't have to try to attract local talent only. Look for someone with telcommuting experience though for your first person.

Comment: And please while you are at it, if this product will havea a significant datbase element, hire a database specialist to design it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with hiring a consultant is that you'll hire somebody in a field you and your team will have no or little experience in. So by definition you'll not be able to judge his knowledge and competence in the field you hire him for (that makes sense doesn't it?).

So in the end it comes down to **trust**. There are good and bad consultants and if I read your question I assume you'll have a tough time finding the right one.

I find it preferable to hire an experienced lead developer instead of hiring a consultant in a startup phase. A consultant always has an external view of your company, he is not directly affected by the design decisions or proposals he is giving to you. If it goes wrong in the end he will have his money anyway. A lead developer instead will be directly influenced by the decisions that get made. As an employee he is also dependend on the long-term success of the company.

If the lead-developer get's to a point where he isn't able to make decisions by himself, he will tell you in his own interest to hire a consultant.

---

**Disclaimer:** Nothing against consultants. There are many situations when their external view is a good and needed thing.